# Is there any way to leverage Groovy's collect method in combination with another iterator function?

Tags: groovy, iterator

For example, the groovy [File](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html) class has a nice iterator that will filter out just directories and not files:

```
void eachDir(Closure closure)
```

When I use `eachDir`, I have to use the verbose method of creating the collection first and appending to it:

```
def collection = []    
dir1.eachDir { dir ->
  collection << dir
}
```

Any way to get it back to the nice compact collect syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any "idiomatic" way of doing this, nice riddle! =D

You can try passing the `eachDir`, or any similar function, to a function that will collect its iterations:

```
def collectIterations(fn) {
    def col = []
    fn {
        col << it
    }
    col
}
```

And now you can use it as:

```
def dir = new File('/path/to/some/dir')
def subDirs = collectIterations(dir.&eachDir)

def file = new File('/path/to/some/file')
def lines = collectIterations(file.&eachLine)
```

(that last example is equivalent to `file.readLines()`)

And only for bonus points, you may define this function as a method in the `Closure` class:

```
Closure.metaClass.collectIterations = {->
    def col = []
    delegate.call {
        col << it
    }
    col
}

def dir = new File('/path/to/some/dir')
def subDirs = dir.&eachDir.collectIterations()

def file = new File('/path/to/some/file')
def lines = file.&eachLine.collectIterations()
```

**Update**: On the other hand, you might also do:

```
def col = []    
someDir.eachDir col.&add
```

Which I think is quite less convoluted, but it's not leveraging the `collect` method as you requested :)

Comment: Interesting approaches, update version is what I'll probably start using.

Answer (score 1):

Not for the specific example that you're talking about.  File.eachDir is sort of a weird implementation IMO.  It would have been nice if they implemented iterator() on File so that you could [use the normal iterator methods](http://naleid.com/blog/2008/12/01/groovy-makes-iteration-easy/) on them rather than the custom built ones that just execute a closure.

The easiest way to get a clean one liner that does what you're looking for is to use listFiles instead combined with findAll:

```
dir1.listFiles().findAll { it.directory }
```

If you look at the implementation of eachDir, you'll see that it's doing this (and a whole lot more that you don't care about for this instance) under the covers.

For many similar situations, inject is the method that you'd be looking for to have a starting value that you change as you iterate through a collection:

```
def sum = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].inject(0) { total, elem -> total + elem }
assert 15 == sum
```