# Building a map for parallel step from directory names

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-workflow

I want to run parallel steps for each directory at a particular level in my workspace. I've been trying to use `eachDir()` within a `@NonCPS` method to build a list of directories that I can then loop over with `for (;;)` to build the map to pass to the `parallel` step. It's a lot of hoop-jumping, but this seems close to the required structure.  Currently I'm getting file-not-found when using the directory provided to `eachDir()`.

```
node {
  new File('./subdir').mkdir() // Create directory to find
  dir('ContainingDirectory') {
    def subDirNames = getSubDirNames(pwd())
    echo subDirNames[0] // Expect to see "subdir"
  }
}

@NonCPS
def getSubDirNames(String dirName) {
  // This is throwing FileNotFound
  return new File(dirName).eachDir().collect { it.getName() }
}
```

How do I get a list (or better, a map of closures suitable for passing to `parallel`) from the names of subdirectories of a given directory?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639255/is-there-any-way-to-leverage-groovys-collect-method-in-combination-with-another) to get the subdirectories.

Comment: Wow, so it was a groovy problem and not a pipeline problem. Who'd have thunk?